# JDBC not returning ResultSet records

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Started a new job and need to learn Java (been a .NET developer for over a decade).  A mandate from higher up dictates all new stuff is to be done in Java / Oracle.

So I am running through the PluralSight training and right now I am trying to learn the intricacies of JDBC.

I have the following table in a Oracle Database (also a new tech for me).

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST"."ACCOUNT"
(
"ACCOUNT_ID" NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY VALUE,
"ACCOUNT_NAME" VARCHAR2(20)
"ACCOUNT_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(20)
"ACCOUNT_TYPE" VARCHAR2(20)
)
```

I set up some code using the Repository pattern.  But it is fairly simple:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

IAccountMapper accountMapper = new AccountMapper();
IConfiguration configuration = new OracleConfiguration();

try (
        IDataAccess<ResultSet> dataAccess = new OracleDataAccess(configuration);
        IAccountRepository accountRepo = new AccountRepository(accountMapper, dataAccess);
        ){

    //nothing here
    List<Account> accounts = accountRepo.query(new AllAccountsSpecification());


} catch (Exception e){
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

}

The IDataAccess interface:

```
public interface IDataAccess<T> {

    T get(String query) throws SQLException;
}
```

All of my implementation is in the base classes and the subclasses are referenced - ie:

```
public interface IOracleDataAccess extends IDataAccess<ResultSet>{

}

public class OracleDataAccess extends DataAccessBase<ResultSet> implements IOracleDataAccess {

public OracleDataAccess(IConfiguration configuration) throws SQLException {
    super(configuration);
}
```

The implementation of the IDataAccess (a base class where T is the entity used by the repo):

```
public abstract class DataAccessBase<T> implements AutoCloseable {

protected final IConfiguration configuration;
protected Connection connection;
protected PreparedStatement statement;
protected ResultSet resultSet;

    public DataAccessBase(IConfiguration configuration) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(configuration.getConnectionString(), 
                configuration.getUsername(),  configuration.getPassword());
    }

    public T get(String query) throws SQLException {
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        return (T)statement.executeQuery();
    }
}
```

This DataAccess class is injected into my Repository class and is used to return the results:

```
public abstract class ReadOnlyRepositoryBase<T> implements IReadOnlyRepository<T> {

protected final IMapper<ResultSet, T> mapper;
protected final IDataAccess<ResultSet> database;

public ReadOnlyRepositoryBase(IMapper<ResultSet, T> mapper, IDataAccess<ResultSet> database) {
    this.mapper = mapper;
    this.database = database;
}

public List<T> query(ISpecification specification){
    List<T> entities = new ArrayList<>;

    try {

        System.out.println(specification.toSqlQuery());
        //This is what is output:  
        //SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT

        //this returns 1 record when:  "select tablespace_name, table_name from user_tables"
        //returns no records when "select * from account"
        ResultSet rs = database.get(specification.toSqlQuery());

        //loop is never entered for "select * from account"
        //runs once for "select tablespace_name, table_name from user_tables"
        while(rs.next()){
            entities.add(mapper.map(rs));
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqlEx){
        sqlEx.printStackTrace();
    }

    return entities;
}
}
```

The problem is nothing is coming back (the ResultSet next() method returns false) This SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT
```

Returns 2 records from the Oracle SQL Developer IDE - but nothing in code.

If I run this query from code:

```
"SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME, TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES"
```

I get 1 record back (TEST, ACCOUNT)

Do I need to further qualify the tables in the SQL to get records back?

I am logged into the database with the same credentials I am connecting with - so I do not think it is a permission thing.

Comment: The code you've shared is not enough to figure out the problem. Please share more code about the flow, entry data, Etc.

Comment: Please insert `System.println( specification.toSqlQuery() );` statement (or some other code which will print this to a log) just after `try {` and before `ResultSet rs = dat ....`, then run a code and check a console (or log) - please copy a statement printed in the console or the log, and paste it to the question.

Comment: If you've just created the table and inserted the two rows in SQL Developer, did you `commit` in that session before querying from Java?

Comment: @AlexPoole - no those records were inserted via the IDE yesterday.

Comment: @krokodilko - added the code and the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel like an idiot - but I imagine I am not the first here.  @AlexPoole was spot on.  I had inserted the records through the IDE - but apparently
I did not commit them.  Coming from SQL Server - I do not need to commit after a

```
Insert into [Table] values (stuff)
```

I guess that is different with Oracle.

Comment: There is an option in the SQL Developer preferences to turn on autocommit, but I've never felt the need to - I prefer the explicit and manual transaction control (but then I've been doing it that way for a long time...). I'd avoid autocommit via JDBC too, personally. (And no, you're very much not the first... it's the first question I ask when there seems to be a data discrepancy!)